# How to create a MySQL User with permissions on databases by mask (for existing DBs and future)

Tags: mysql

For instance we have DB: `project1_db1`, `project1_db2`, `project1_db3` ... - in future will be `..db4` and `..db5` etc..

How to create a MySQL User with permissions on all `*project1_*` databases?

And if database `project1_blablabla` will be created - this User should has permission on it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is great solution:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `project1\_%`.* TO 'username'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'userpass';
```

In this example we should use `\_` to escape the `_`

If you don't have `_` underscore in your database name, for example `forum1`, `forum2`, `forum3` :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `forum%`.* TO 'username'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'userpass';
```

Note! use `` ` `` instead of `'` in the database name